# Server Version Exception trying to open SkeetySoftDefects.mdf in SQL Server 2008

Tags: c#, sql-server, mdf

I'm working through Chapter 12 of Jon Skeet's **C# In Depth** (a certain Pantheon of books candidate) and I get the following error when trying to run any of the choices from the console menu displayed for Project SqlExamples:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException occurred
  Message=The database 'E:\MY VAULTS\PERSONALVAULT\PERSONAL\JOB SEARCH\TUTORIALS\C# IN DEPTH\C# IN DEPTH CODE\AUTHORS\DATABASES\SKEETYSOFTDEFECTS.MDF'
  cannot be opened because it is version 706. 
  This server supports version 662 and earlier. 
  A downgrade path is not supported.  ...
```

I think I'm running SQL Server 2008 R2.
From the googling I've done, it seems that the .MDF file referenced in the error was created in SQL Server 2012.  However, in Skeet's book he appears to contradict that, as follows:
  "The database is in SQL Server **2005** format to make it easy to play with, even if you don’t have 
   the latest version of SQL Server installed ..."

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried upgrading to SQL Server 2012? It sounds like that's your problem.